# Is it a good practice to call other components inside map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am working on some react optimization in the file Group.js i am printing the list of user properties and the address is an object of user property. I am breaking into a Useraddress component so that later i can use it later.

I want  to know is this a good practice to call component inside the map function.
is it optimized?
How to fix it or what is the alternative for it?

Group.js

```
import { MyContext } from "./App";
import "./App.css";
import UserAddress from "./UserAddress";


const Groups = () => {

  // console.log("Child Rerender",arr)
  const users = useContext(MyContext)

  return (
    <div className="grp-container">
      <h3>This Group has following members</h3>
      <ul>
        {users.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {index + 1} Name : {item.name} 
              UserName : {item.username}
              Email : {item.email}
              phone : {item.phone}
              website : {item.website}
              <UserAddress address = {item.address}/>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(Groups);
```

UserAddress.js

```
import React from "react";

const UserAddress = ({ address }) => {
  const userAddress = [address];
console.log("addrss rendered")
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {userAddress.map((item, index) => {
          return <li key={index}>City: {item.city}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserAddress;
```

Comment: its perfectly reasonable. This question seems more like a code style question than trying to solve a specific problem. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't see how anything in the code you've provided would *need* optimization. But I will say making `address` an array just to map over it seems unnecessary. Rendering components is not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with what you've done, but in react, if you leave the `map` functions in the return call, then every render I believe that map will occur again.

```
const Groups = () => {

  // console.log("Child Rerender",arr)
  const users = useContext(MyContext)

  return (
    <div className="grp-container">
      <h3>This Group has following members</h3>
      <ul>
        {users.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {index + 1} Name : {item.name} 
              UserName : {item.username}
              Email : {item.email}
              phone : {item.phone}
              website : {item.website}
              <UserAddress address = {item.address}/>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default memo(Groups);

If you want to avoid that you can do useMemo like so:

```
const Groups = () => {

  // console.log("Child Rerender",arr)
  const users = useContext(MyContext)

  const userMapping = useMemo(() => {
    return users.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              {index + 1} Name : {item.name} 
              UserName : {item.username}
              Email : {item.email}
              phone : {item.phone}
              website : {item.website}
              <UserAddress address = {item.address}/>
            </li>
          );
        })
  }, [users])

  return (
    <div className="grp-container">
      <h3>This Group has following members</h3>
      <ul>
        {userMapping}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(Groups);
```